# What does "vs. XX, vs XX" mean?

Tags: meaning

> The best design showed a 110% increase in click-throughs vs. the control design, and was projected to deliver a gain of between 80 and 120%, once deployed.
>
> The program delivered a gain of 5%—this is the performance of all of
>   the tested designs vs. control, **vs. the stats above which are those
>   of the best performing single design.**

How can I interpret "vs. the stats (versus statistics)" here? I think the sentence structure of the bold part is somewhat awkward. Shouldn't there be "and" before "vs. the stats"? Does the bold part mean "the 5% performance is the performance of all of the tested designs compared to the statistics above which are those of the best performing single design"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is kind of confusing that there are two “vs” statements. I don’t think an “and” would make sense here. Here is what I think this whole thing means: “performance of all tested design vs. control” is one measure, and “the best performing single design” is another measure. I interpret the 5% gain as being the first measure (all tested design vs control), totally unrelated to the second measure. Whatever “stats above” that exist are for the second measure, “the best performing single design”. I could be wrong, though- I agree that it is phrased awkwardly. Do you have a picture of “the stats above”? That might help clarify things.

Comment: There is a statistics in the above paragraph, which is:
The best design showed a 110% increase in click-throughs vs. the control design, and was projected to deliver a gain of between 80 and 120%, once deployed.

Comment: Thank you, that first paragraph makes things a little clearer. I still agree that the second paragraph has awkward phrasing but I also still think my original interpretation is correct: the best single-performing design has a certain estimated gain (80-120%), while a program that measures all tested designs against the control has a different gain (5%).